# Is there a neat way to get hold of the number of times pine script strategy.exit has reached limit profit (maxprofit)?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, pine-script-v5, maximum-profit-problem

I would like to find a way on how to track the number of times that the below strategy has taken maxProfit. The idea is to stop the strategy to run once, we hit certain number of maxProfit.

`strategy.exit(id="XL STP", profit = maxProfit, loss = nRes*100)`

I do not know a way to track this number while the strategy is being executed.

Answer (score 0):

Use an integer counter variable that you increment once per trade at most only if the current profit is above your **maxProfit** variable

The `strategy.position_avg_price` gives you the entry price
So the difference for example for a long between the `high` and `strategy.position_avg_price` should give you the current PnL of your trade

You can track the higher/lower points of your trades like this

```
var MaxReached = 0.0        // Max high/low reached since beginning of trade.

// resetting min/max at each signal
if signal_candle[1]

    MaxReached := strategy.position_size > 0 ? high : low

MaxReached := strategy.position_size > 0
 ? math.max(nz(MaxReached, high), high)
 : strategy.position_size < 0 ? math.min(nz(MaxReached,Rlow), low) : na
```

Comment: Hi Dave thanks for replying! I have tried your approach but to no avail :(

Comment: Refer to my code below on the second answer segment

Comment: why do you multiply by 100 here?


if(math.abs(strategy.position_avg_price - MaxReached)*100 >= maxProfit)

Comment: because my maxProfit is in cents so 100 is actually 1 dollar and I need to convert the dollar price to cents

Answer (score 0):

I did Dave method above but still not working as expected.

```
//reset profit reached to zero if a new day
if(ta.change(time('1D')))
    numberMaxProfitReached := 0
    MaxReached := na

if(numberMaxProfitReached < maxNumberProfit)

    MaxReached := strategy.position_size > 0 ? math.max(nz(MaxReached, high), high) : strategy.position_size < 0 ? math.min(nz(MaxReached, low), low) : na
    
    if(math.abs(strategy.position_avg_price - MaxReached)*100 >= maxProfit)
        numberMaxProfitReached = numberMaxProfitReached + 1

    if(shortCond)
        strategy.entry("Sell", strategy.short, 1)
    else if(longCond)
        strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, 1)

    if (strategy.position_size < 0)
        strategy.exit(id="XS STP", profit = maxProfit, loss = nRes*100)
        if(buySignal)
            MaxReached := strategy.position_size > 0 ? high : low
            strategy.close("Sell")
    else if(strategy.position_size > 0)
        strategy.exit(id="XL STP", profit = maxProfit, loss = nRes*100) 
        if(sellSignal)
            MaxReached := strategy.position_size > 0 ? high : low
            strategy.close("Buy")
```

The idea is to increment maxProfitReached by 1 every time we have hit our maxProfit. However, when I backtested it, it still doesn't increment the maxProfitReached number although conditions are met.